# OS X application is keep being killed after OS migration

Tags: macos, appstore-sandbox

One of users of my OS X application has migrated his mac to new MBP and my application, which is sandboxed, signed w/ developer-id certificate, and ad-hoc distributed, keep being killed. At console, I found the following logs.

> xpcd[352]: restored permissions (100600 -> 100700) on
>   /Users/myname/Library/Containers/com.company.AppMac/Container.plist 
>   com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[342]: (com.company.AppMac.63040[1567])
>   Exited: Killed: 9  com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[342]:
>   (com.company.AppMac.63040[1598]) Exited: Killed: 9 
>   com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[342]: (com.company.AppMac.63040[1616])
>   Exited: Killed: 9

I have no clue what caused this kind of error. How can I fix it?

Comment: Have them delete and re download?

Comment: @uchuugaka AFAIK, yes they did.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a code-signing issue. Maybe it is related to not signing your nested bundles (see http://furbo.org/2013/10/17/code-signing-and-mavericks/)

Comment: Actually helper app and 3rd-party framework, HockeySDK, are included bundle. However all of them are signed "Developer ID" certificate and `spctl` says app bundle is OK.

Comment: If I delete `~/Library/Containers/com.company.AppMac`, it doesn't crash.